# Remove class when no defined element is in view

Tags: javascript, navbar

I have added Menuspy.js to my code and everything seems to work perfectly. However, when there is no cached element in view, the last active element remains active. I want to remove this `active` class once that is the case (also, I really want to use vanilla JS, so I am not looking for a jquery alternative).
I have tried to check for the element height and return if it goes past that pos, but so far I have not found a way to succesfully get this to work.

Here's a JSFiddle running the menuspy code: https://jsfiddle.net/horbp9cq/17/

I added a 4th section in this example, while leaving it out in the navbar. You will see Section 3 remains highlighted.

Hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: Please share/recreate a working sample of your code with menuspy.js included.

Comment: @norcaljohnny I have updated the post with a working sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this plagin doesn't handle situation like yours. As a work around you can add

```
<li style="display:none"><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
```

to your main-header menu

Comment: Good point, that is one way of handling it. I would prefer to make the plugin figure this out though since it keeps the html code cleaner.